# Merge different datasets based on condition in R data.table

Tags: r, if-statement, join, merge, data.table

Suppose I have a major dataset called "**main**" and three other datasets called "**df1**", "**df2**" and "**df3**".

- "**main**" includes: year, colA, colB, colC
- "**df1**" includes: year, colD
- "**df2**" includes: year, colE
- "**df3**" includes: year, colF

I want to merge **colD**, **colE**, **colF** of df1, df2, df3 to "**main**" using the year column to rename that merged column to "merged_value".

The logic is like this:

- If colA == "Category1", then merge **df1** to "main"
- If colA == "Category2", then merge **df2** to "main"
- If colA == "Category3", then merge **df3** to "main"

The only way I could think of now is to break the main into 3 subsets and do the merge (shown below), but are there any simpler approach to this?

```
main_sub1 = main[colA=="Category1"][df1, on="year"]
main_sub2 = main[colA=="Category2"][df2, on="year"]
main_sub3 = main[colA=="Category3"][df3, on="year"]
main_comb = rbind(main_sub1, main_sub2, main_sub3)
```

Comment: Would you edit your post then add `dput(your_data)`?

Comment: Please make a small reproducible example to illustrate the problem. 2 or 3 rows from each of `main`, `df1`, and `df2` should be plenty (choose rows that illustrate the problem well).

Comment: I updated my question with my current approach. I think it'll help illustrate the problem better. Thanks

Comment: You updated your question with the approach but we have no sample data. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `colA` and its `"Category#"` to each of the respective `df#`s, merging on `year` and `colA`, coalescing the `merged_value`:

```r
main[df1[, colA := "Category1"], merged_value := i.colD, on = .(year, colA)]
main[df2[, colA := "Category2"], merged_value := fcoalesce(i.colE, merged_value), on = .(year, colA)]
main[df3[, colA := "Category3"], merged_value := fcoalesce(i.colF, merged_value), on = .(year, colA)]
main
#     year      colA  colB  colC merged_value
#    <int>    <char> <int> <int>        <int>
# 1:  2001 Category1     1     1           11
# 2:  2002 Category2     2     2           12
# 3:  2003 Category3     3     3           13
# 4:  2004 Category4     4     4           NA
```

---

Data

```r
main <- data.table(year=2001:2004, colA=paste0("Category",1:4), colB=1:4, colC=1:4)
df1 <- data.table(year=2001:2004, colD=11:14)
df2 <- data.table(year=2001:2004, colE=11:14)
df3 <- data.table(year=2001:2004, colF=11:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, similar to @r2evans (and using @r2evans data), but utilizing a single merge. Basically rowbind `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`, leveraging the `id` param

```
setnames(df1,"colD","val")
rbindlist(setNames(list(df1,df2,df3), paste0("Category",1:3)), id="colA")[main, on=.(colA,year)]
```

Output:

```
        colA  year   val  colB  colC
      <char> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1: Category1  2001    11     1     1
2: Category2  2002    12     2     2
3: Category3  2003    13     3     3
4: Category4  2004    NA     4     4
```